# RAII and Qt signals

Tags: c++, qt, raii

I'm trying to understand and use RAII and wanted opinions on this implementation:

I want the RAII PauseProcessRAII to emit a signal and another one in the destructor.  Example:

```
// Header
public:
    PauseProcessRAII(QObject *parent = 0);
    void Execute();
    ~PauseProcessRAII();

signals:
    void PauseProcess(bool pause_process);

// Source

PauseProcessRAII::~PauseProcessRAII()
{
    emit PauseProcess(false);
}

void PauseProcessRAII::Execute()
{
    emit PauseProcess(true);
}

// MainWindow code
void MainWindow::OnPauseProcessRAII(bool pause_process)
{
    qDebug() << "pause_process: " << pause_process;
}

void MainWindow::OnButtonSaveClicked()
{
    PauseProcessRAII pauseProcessRAII(this);
    connect(&pauseProcessRAII, &PauseProcessRAII::PauseProcess, this, &MainWindow::OnPauseProcess);
    pauseProcessRAII.Execute();

    // ... Some code runs
    // ... pauseRAII desctructor is called
}
```

When I run the code both emits are firing as expected. My question is this a good solution? At first I though the emit call in PauseProcessRAII destructor wouldn't have worked because it may have destroyed the signal and slot connection. Of course that would mean I would have to add the connect to every function that I use it on.

Comment: This is not a RAII idiom. In RAII, a resource is aquired in constructor and destroyed in destructor. I do not see any resource aquisition in constructor (I am ready to consider emitting a signal a form of resource management). Also every RAII class have to have a carefully thought through copy, move and assignment policy, and I do not see it here either.

Comment: There are no resources here besides the connection of the event to the main window. Hence, transferring ownership partially is questionable (maybe a questionable QT design)

Comment: At first I was going to emit the signal in the constructor but the connect has not been made yet so it wouldn't fire.  Thanks I guess I have more reading to do on it.  I took away the idea about RAII was create it on the stack so when the function goes out of scope the destructor will be called.  And I needed that to happen but emit a signal instead

Comment: The resource that I'm trying to identify is the bool that is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea is fundamentally broken if your premise is that the code indicated by "Some code runs" runs long enough to block the GUI. If so: don't do that. The only code that is supposed to ever execute in the GUI thread is short, run-to-completion code that doesn't take long enough for the user to notice.

If the time taken by "Some code runs" is very short - on the order of single milliseconds at most - then you can certainly use such a construct. The term RAII doesn't apply here, as you're dealing with some sort of a scope guard.

If you wish, you can forgo the `execute` method and perform the connection in the constructor:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/scopeguard-signal-34910879
// main.cpp
#include <QtCore>

class ScopeSignaller : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_SIGNAL void inScope(bool);
   template <typename F>
   ScopeSignaller(QObject * target, F && slot, QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
      connect(this, &ScopeSignaller::inScope, target, std::forward<F>(slot));
      inScope(true);
   }
   ~ScopeSignaller() {
      inScope(false);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
   ScopeSignaller s(&app, +[](bool b){ qDebug() << "signalled" << b; });
}

#include "main.moc"
```